# OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]

Tags: ssis, ssms, etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-2017

This is the Error message

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC0209077 occurred

This is my oracle date source format

```
31-DEC-18
```

and this is my destination table

```
[COVERAGEEFFECTIVEDATE] [varchar](10) NULL
```

Comment: Dates don't have a "format"; they are binary values. Also, if it's a date, why are you trying to insert it into a `varchar(1)`? A date is **never** going to fit into a single character. Use a date and time data type.

Comment: Thank you i changed data type and it worked